# Entity Framework Core Stored Proc without DbSet

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am calling a stored proc from EF Core 1.1, following the advice on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

But I created a class specifically that matches the shape of data returned from the stored proc

```
List<MyStoredProcResultType> results = context.MyStoredProcResultType
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.MyStoredProc {0}", someParam)
    .ToList();
```

But this means I have to create a `DbSet` for `MyStoredProcResultType` in the `Context` and now it is legal to code this

`context.MyStoredProcResultType.Where(..)`

but of course this does not work.

Is there a way to call the stored proc against the `Context` rather than a `DbSet` and put the results into a type I create?

Comment: Not possible as of EF Core 2.0 See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1862

Comment: @Smit If you want to place that in an answer I'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presently, in EF Core 2.0 RTM version, `FromSql` can be used only with the types which are defined as EntityType in your model. The restriction is there because, EF Core has metadata about the EntityType and knows how to materialize them. So for any other type (like custom DTO/result type), FromSql does not work.

This is [tracking issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1862) on EF Core GitHub repository which is tracking exactly what you are looking for.

EF Core 2.1.0 is planning to add some support for querying views. [Tracking issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9290). Which could enable scenario like yours, if you are ok with letting EF Core know about the custom type you want to use during model building. It wouldn't mapped as EntityType/Table but EF Core would still compute metadata around it to support queries like above.

Answer (score 12):

Since EF Core 2.1 you can use [Query Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types)

You have to register your result class as a Query type this way:

```
modelBuilder.Query<MyStoredProcResultType>();
```

Then, simply use:

```
var results = Context.Query<MyStoredProcResultType>()
                     .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.MyStoredProc {0}", someParam)
                     .ToList()
```

Credits go to @Ivan Stoev for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52003734/8358565

Comment: To anyone reading this answer, there is a new way to do it from .NET Core 3 onwards. As pointed out by antoninod, please read SO answer from @Ivan Stoev following the link.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck in the same problem, having to add DTOs as DbSets when using Entity Framework Core with stored procedures that returns nested objects. After some research, I found these packages:

https://github.com/verdie-g/StoredProcedureEFCore

https://github.com/snickler/EFCore-FluentStoredProcedure

Please give credit to the package authors.