# execute stored procedure in entity Framework Core without expecting map to dbset

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on .NET CORE, Entity Framework core. I have stored procedure that I need to execute from .NET class. My stored procedure takes number of 'Context' and I don't know how to deal this, although I have dataView which is final exception.

I wounder if I can use my dataView instead of context.dataModel class, current implementation (Context.Claims.FromSql)

### dataView

```
public class ClaimDataView
{
    public Guid ClaimId { get; set; }
    public int IdNum { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public ClaimAttributionActions Action { get; set; }
    public bool ActiveStateForRole { get; set; }

}
```

### stored-Procedure call

```
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
public Guid ConsultationId { get; set; }

  var userParam = new SqlParameter("@UserVal", UserId);
  var clientParam = new SqlParameter("@ClientVal", ConsultationId);
  var consultationParam = new SqlParameter("@ConsultationVal", ConsultationId);

 //**************need help in following line
  var query = Context.Claims.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.ListUserClaims @userId=@UserVal, @clientId=@ClientVal, @consultationId=@ConsultationVal"
            , userParam, clientParam, consultationParam);
```

### new update

### moduleContext Class

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       //other models....
       modelBuilder.Query<ClaimDataView>();
    }
```

### Stored Procedure executing from

```
 var query = Context.Query<UserDataView>().FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.ListUserClaims @userId=@UserVal, @clientId=@ClientVal, @consultationId=@ConsultationVal"
            , userParam, clientParam, consultationParam);
```

### error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'UserDataView' because this type is not included in the model for the context.
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbQuery`1.get_EntityType()
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 8.0+):**

EF Core 8.0 finally added support for [Raw SQL queries for unmapped types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#raw-sql-queries-for-unmapped-types) via [SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.sqlquery?view=efcore-8.0) or [SqlQueryRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.sqlqueryraw?view=efcore-8.0), so now you can simply use

```cs
var query = Context.SqlQueryRaw<ClaimDataView>(...);
```

without registering the `ClaimDataView` in the model.

**Original:**

You can utilize the [Query Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) introduced in EF Core 2.1.

First you need to register you class as query type:

```cs
modelBuilder.Query<ClaimDataView>();
```

Then you can use `Context.Query<ClaimDataView>()` in place of your current `Context.Claims`:

```cs
var query = Context.Query<ClaimDataView>().FromSql(...);
```

---

**Update (EF Core 3.x+)**:

Starting with EF Core 3.0, query types have been [consolidated with entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#qt) and renamed to [Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types), so the corresponding code is

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ClaimDataView>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

and

```cs
var query = Context.Set<ClaimDataView>().FromSql(...);
```

Comment: many thanks to put me in right direction, however I am still getting no where... I have update my question ... refer code below newUpate heading... I have added in model class but have not create any configuration for ClaimDataView. I am not sure I need that but got error ... refer above

Comment: It shouldn't be creating `DbSet` for `ClaimDataView`. Make sure you have no `DbSet<ClaimDataView` in your context, also no `modelBuilder.Entity<ClaimDataView>()` calls.

Comment: Noticed that your updated code uses `UserDataView` in some parts and `ClaimDataView` in other. Typo? Or the cause of the new exception?

Comment: Is there a way to specify the *source* of the keyless types? I can call a sproc, and say that the result should go to some keyless entity type, but how do I add the sproc to my DB from OnModelCreating in the first place? I would like to say `modelBuilder.Entity<T>().HasNoKey().FromSql("CREATE PROCEDURE Something...");`

Comment: #@DaveCousineau Currently (v3.1.4) there is no such capability.

Comment: @IvanStoev just bumped into this comment randomly. I think the answer to what I asked is that to create a sproc from your model, you would need to add it to a custom migration, not define it in OnModelCreating. But I think it's easier to maintain from the database side anyway, saving a CREATE script in your repo.

Comment: also note that `FromSql` has been replaced with `FromSqlInterpolated` and `FromSqlRaw`.

Comment: Question: "how do I call SP without expecting map to dbset". Answer: use DbSet. Why is this an accepted answer?

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin I guess it depends what you're trying to do. The reason to avoid DbSet in this case is to not map your entity to a table. Keyless types register your type with the EF model without creating a table for it on the DB side. You can then use a sproc with your type.

Comment: +1, thanks for the answer - I refer back to this now and again.  I think an easy thing to miss is the .ToView(null) after the .HasNoKey() directive, otherwise the migration builder is still going to try to create a table from the snapshot without it.

Comment: @Ajt EF8 is still far from release point, so it's too early to say what will be available there. I in general do not comment preview (even release candidate) software features as they by definition can (and usually do) change. Same for implementation details and (potential) bugs.

Answer (score 6):

If you are not on version 2.1, you will need to add:

```
public DbSet<ClaimDataView> ClaimDataView { get; set; }
```

to your moduleContext. 
And add NotMapped to your class:

```
[NotMapped]
public class ClaimDataView
```