# Mapping stored procedure results to a custom class using EF Core FromSql returns instances with default values

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PLogin
    @pin varchar(50), @ipaddress varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    //Some code here ...

    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[QRelaceUzivatele_Aktivni] WHERE Pin = @pin AND IPAdresa=@ipaddress 
END
```

I need to execute it from ASP MVC using EF Core 2.1.

I have used the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52003734/2224701).

I have a custom C# class `AktivniRelaceUzivatele` that maps the fields of the `QRelaceUzivatele_Aktivni` view.

```
public class AktivniRelaceUzivatele
{
    int ProvozID { get; set; }
    string NazevProvozu { get; set; }
    int UzivatelID { get; set; }
    string PIN { get; set; }
    string Nick { get; set; }
```

In MVC controller I call:

```
var qpin = new SqlParameter("p", pin);
var qip = new SqlParameter("ip", ip);
var ar = db.Query<AktivniRelaceUzivatele>()
        .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.PLogin  @pin=@p, @ipaddress=@ip", qpin, qip).FirstOrDefault();
```

In dbContext class I have added:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Query<AktivniRelaceUzivatele>();
```

I get no compile error the stored procedure gets executed but the result values are not insterted into objects's properties, instead I get instances that contain only default values like `null`, 0 etc.

Comment: Can u try to add public classifiers to class variables? I think I got the similar issues, where I missed both getters and setters and public classifiers.

Comment: @Naruto Yes, my bad... uf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try to add public classifiers to class variables? I think I got the similar issues, where I missed both getters and setters and public classifiers.