# Calling stored procedure from Entity Framework Core

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework 6, we had the option to run a stored procedure that returns a specific model object with code like this:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<MyModelClass>("SomeStoredProcedure @p0", param1).ToList();
```

where `MyModelClass` represents the result set from the stored procedure.

My question is do we have similar kind of option in Entity Framework Core? So far I've been able to find `FromSQL` but (I could be wrong) this method expects the dbset name, whereas I want to provide plain model class name (because there could be multiple stored procedures with multiple models)

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703599/mapping-stored-procedure-results-to-a-custom-class-using-ef-core-fromsql-returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out that for this kind of scenario we'll have to use **Keyless entity types** feature provided by Entity Framework Core 3.0. Here is how it worked form me.

First of all, in the **OnModelCreating** event of **DbContext**, introduce the entity type like this

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<MyModelClassName>(m=>
            {
                m.HasNoKey();
            });
    }
```

Now we'll simply call the stored procedure like this

```
context.Set<MyModelClassName>().FromSqlRaw("MyStoredProcedureName").ToList();
```

Thanks.