# EFCore Creates Unnecessary Table from Data Model used to call SPROC,

Tags: asp.net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I'm calling sprocs from asp.net core using Entity framework core in an MVC/Razor/WebAPI app.
Newer dev so apologies if this is nube. I have read everything I can find on sprocs from EF...

**Issue:**
When I setup my app to call a sproc, EF Core updates my DB (via the next Migration I run) to create an empty table based on the model I created to retrieve output from the sproc.

Example:
I have a a sproc that returns two columns

```
SELECT customerID, customerName from MyTable
```

I add a simple POCO MyModel using [Keyless] directive

```
namespace MyApp.Models 
{
    [Keyless]
    public class MyModel 
    {
        public int customerID { get; set; }
        public string customerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then register the class in my ApplicationDBContext

```
public virtual DbSet<MyModel> MyModel { get; set; }
```

I can now call the sproc from my pages using:

```
public List<MyModel> CustomerList { get; set; }
```

and

```
CustomerList = _context.MySproc
                     .FromSqlRaw($"MySproc")
                     .ToList();
```

When I next run a migration, EF adds migration code to create a table based on my model, which I don't believe I need.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
     name: "VerifyEmailAndStripeCustomerID",
     columns: table => new
     {
     customerID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
     customerName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(128)", maxLength: 128, nullable: true)
     },
```

How can I call my sprocs without this table creation behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by: [execute stored procedure in entity Framework Core without expecting map to dbset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003432/execute-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-core-without-expecting-map-to-dbset)

[Keyless] merely specifies a table that doesn't have a primary key - so you need to go one step further on model creating to tell it not to create the backing table:

1. Remove the `DbSet<MyModel>` property from your contex (you may be able to leave it, but it would confusing since it's not backed by a table...)
2. In the OnModelCreating of the context, register and/or manipulate `MyModel`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

3. Populate the model with the following:

```
CustomerList = Context.Set<MyModel>().FromSql($"MySproc").ToList();
```

Comment: Did this answer you question?