# How to fetch non-entity data using DTO from stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have written a stored procedure which returns data like this:

```
Datex       Score  
-------------------
2023-04-05    1
2023-04-12    1
2023-04-19    1
2023-04-26    2
2023-05-03    2
2023-05-10    4
2023-05-17    4
2023-05-24    4
2023-05-31    5
2023-06-07    6
```

I wish to call this from EF using C#.

I created a DTO object as

```
public class CummGraphDTO
{
    public DateTime Datex { get; set; }
    public int? Score { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to call it with this statement:

```
await _context.Database.SqlQuery<CummGraphDTO>($"exec dbo.GetCummulative").ToListAsync();
```

However, it does not seem to work. What is the correct way to fetch the data?

Comment: *"it does not seem to work"*. That's not a problem description. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which includes the exact behaviour you expect and the exact behaviour you see. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a proper question and then update yours accordingly. You also need to provide ALL the RELEVANT code. `ToListAsync` is going to return a list but you're not assigning that to anything in what you posted. We can't tell whether that's because you omitted that part or you're actually not doing it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - "selective reading". Did you not read the next line - What is the correct way to fetch the data? I feel its pretty relevant data to answer and actually I got the answer from chatgpt and c-sharpcorner  .  com. Posting the answer here so its useful for others.

Comment: _"actually I got the answer from chatgpt and c-sharpcorner . com"_ - too bad they gave you the wrong answer, but that's typical for both.

Comment: *"Did you not read the next line"*. Yes, I did read the next line. It doesn't contain a problem description either. This is not a place where you say "I want to do X, tell me how". You need to describe your actual problem. If you try something and it doesn't work, you don't just tell us that it doesn't work. You need to describe exactly how and where it doesn't work. There are certain things expected of you as someone posting a question here.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Well atleast it works for me rather than going down the rabbit hole of stackoverflow. Thanks but I am done....multiple times I have got very clear answers from those 2 and saved time.

Answer (score -1):

1. Add DB Set public DbSet CummGraphDTO { get; set; }
2. builder.Entity().HasNoKey().ToView(null);  since there is no key
3. CummGraphDTO has same fields as output of SP with same properties
4. var data = await _context.CummGraphDTO.FromSqlRaw($"exec dbo.GetCummulative").ToListAsync();

Works like charm !!!

Comment: You don't _have to_ add a `DbSet<T>` for querying stored procedure output, see [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698359/entity-framework-core-stored-proc-without-dbset).

Comment: Does not work if I dont add DbSet<T> when I am expecting more fields in return. Also, I dont see how its duplicate. Anyways.