# Why Dapper faster than Dapper plus?

Tags: c#, performance, dapper, dapper-plus

Given a simple test:

**Using Dapper:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
      Connection.Execute("UPDATE User SET Name = 'Max'");
}
```

The duration of this operation is as follows measured with a `StopWatch`:

> RunTime 00:00:37.51 Duration: 00:00:37.5150734 Duration in Milli
> seconds: 37515

**Using Dapper plus:**

```
User user = new User();
user.Name = "Max";
DapperPlusManager.Entity<User>().Table("User");
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
       Connection.BulkUpdate(user);
}
```

The duration of this operation is as follows measured with a `StopWatch`:

> RunTime 00:00:39.85 Duration: 00:00:39.8553959 Duration in Milli
> seconds: 39855

I did this test in different scenarios and Dapper is always faster than Dapper plus

The question is clear, why is Dapper faster than Dapper Plus? What can cause such a thing?

Note: i'm using Sqlite with entity framework

Comment: Relevant? http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-write-fast-code.html

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43590624/5779732. The tests you are executing are not comparable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is Dapper faster than Dapper Plus? What can cause such a thing?

a) `BulkUpdate`, as its name implies, is for bulk updates (i.e. updating multiple rows at once). You are calling it one at a time. You want to do a [single](https://github.com/zzzprojects/Dapper-Plus/wiki/dapper-plus-bulk-update#dapper-plus---bulk-update-ienumerabletentity) call to it, not 10,000, to get the benefits.

b) The latter code likely needs reflection (e.g. to realise that there is a `Name` property) in a way that the former code doesn't. That will incur some performance cost.

Fixing a) is almost certainly what you need to do. *Also, use a more meaningful test whereby you are updating 10,000 different rows - not the same row 10,000 times (since with your current code the simplest fix is to have it execute just once rather than 10,000 times - but I suspect that is not what you want).*

Comment: Okay thank you. And what exactly do you mean by "The latter code likely needs reflection in a way that the former code doesn't"?

Comment: `User user = new User();
user.Name = "Max";
DapperPlusManager.Entity<User>().Table("User");` It probably needs reflection to generate the SQL. e.g. to realise that there is a `Name` property there. The former code doesn't need to do that - it just says 'execute this exact SQL'.